# iOS swift application read data from firestore, data shown on simulator but not in physical device

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My application read the data correctly and all things work as needed but when I run it on my iphone the data is not shown like it is empty or null, I checked the code try to figure out why but I did not find out the problem. and when I read the data directly in " FirstScreenViewController" View Controller the data is appear so I do know exactly where is the problem any help please
My code:

```
//
//  DataManager.swift
//  Aqra3
//
//  Created by Mahmoud Abdelaziz on 14/01/2023.
//


import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class DataManager {
    static let shared = DataManager()
    var delegate: DataManagerDelegate?

    //var dataCache = [String: Any]() // for screen 1 [0] is the title
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    var db: Firestore!
    var db2: Firestore!
    var db3: Firestore!

    //var db4: Firestore!
    //var dailyAdvice = String()
    var screenOneBody = String()
    var screenOneTitle = String()
    var screenTwoBody = String()
    var screenTwoTitle = String()
    var screenThreeBody = String()
    var screenThreeTitle = String()
    
    //private init() {}

    func fetchDataFromFirestore(date: String) {
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        db2 = Firestore.firestore()
        db3 = Firestore.firestore()
        //db4 = Firestore.firestore()
        
        //let topicDay = String(self.currentDateTime.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))// exp Jan 3, 2023

        let screenOne = db.collection("Screen1").document(date)
        screenOne.getDocument{ (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                self.screenOneBody = document.get("Body")! as! String
                self.screenOneTitle = document.get("Title")! as! String
                print("Screen One Body: \(self.screenOneBody) \n")
                print("Screen One Title: \(self.screenOneTitle) \n")
                print("Data: \(date) \n")
               // DispatchQueue.main.async {
               //     self.delegate?.dataDidUpdate()
               // }
                let screenTwo = self.db2.collection("Screen2").document(date)
                screenTwo.getDocument{ (document, error) in
                    if let document = document, document.exists {
                        self.screenTwoBody = document.get("Body")! as! String
                        self.screenTwoTitle = document.get("Title")! as! String
                        print("Screen Two Body: \(self.screenTwoBody) \n")
                        print("Screen Two Title: \(self.screenTwoTitle) \n")
                        print("Data: \(date) \n")
                        
                        let screenThree = self.db3.collection("Screen3").document(date)
                        screenThree.getDocument { (document, error) in
                            if let document = document, document.exists {
                                self.screenThreeBody = document.get("Body")! as! String
                                self.screenThreeTitle = document.get("Title")! as! String
                                print("Screen Three Body: \(self.screenThreeBody) \n")
                                print("Screen Three Title: \(self.screenThreeTitle) \n")
                                print("Data: \(date) \n")
                            } else {
                                        print("Document does not exist")
                                        print("Data: \(date)")
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

protocol DataManagerDelegate {
    func fetchDataFromFirestore(date: String)
    func dataDidUpdate()

}
```

---

```
//
//  FirstScreenViewController.swift
//  Aqra3
//
//  Created by Mahmoud Abdelaziz on 01/01/2023.
//

import UIKit
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestore

class FirstScreenViewController: UIViewController, DataManagerDelegate {
    func fetchDataFromFirestore(date: String) {
        DataManager.shared.fetchDataFromFirestore(date: date)
        changeTheBody()
        DataManager.shared.delegate?.dataDidUpdate()
        
    }
    
    //var newDateFromMenu = SideMenuViewController()
    var db: Firestore!
    let currentDateTime = Date()
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    var refreshTimer = Timer()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var FirstScreenTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstScreenTitle: UITextView!
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true // hide the back button
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
        db = Firestore.firestore()
        //self.navigationController!.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.red // this if you want to cahnge the navigationBar color without change the global tint color

        //DataManager.shared.fetchDataFromFirestore()
        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleGesture))

        swipeLeft.direction = .right
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
        DataManager.shared.delegate = self

        //let topicDay = String(self.currentDateTime.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))// exp Jan 3, 2023
        //DataManager.shared.fetchDataFromFirestore(date: topicDay)
        changeTheBody()
        
        refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeTheBody), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    

    }
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        refreshTimer.invalidate()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        refreshTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 60.0, target: self, selector: #selector(changeTheBody), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    
    @objc func changeTheBody() {
        FirstScreenTextView.text =  "\(DataManager.shared.screenOneBody)"
        //FirstScreenTextView.semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft
        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        style.lineSpacing = 10  // adjust line spacing as needed
        style.baseWritingDirection = .rightToLeft
        style.alignment = .justified
        let attributes = [    NSAttributedString.Key.paragraphStyle: style]
        FirstScreenTextView.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: FirstScreenTextView.text, attributes: attributes)
        FirstScreenTextView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
        FirstScreenTextView.textColor = UIColor.white
        firstScreenTitle.textColor = UIColor.white
        firstScreenTitle.text =  "\(DataManager.shared.screenOneTitle)"

        refreshControl.endRefreshing()

    }
    @objc func handleGesture(gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        if gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "fromFirstScreenToMainScreen", sender: self)
        }
    }
    
   /* override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResult" {
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! SideMenuViewController
 
        }
    }*/
    func dataDidUpdate() {
        changeTheBody()
    }
}
```

---

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  AQRA3
//
//  Created by Mahmoud Abdelaziz on 01/01/2023.
//

import UIKit
import FirebaseCore
@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    let currentDateTime = Date()



    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        let topicDay = String(self.currentDateTime.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted))// exp Jan 3, 2023
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        DataManager.shared.fetchDataFromFirestore(date: topicDay)
        return true
    }

    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what is happening here.

When you read the data in your `AppDelegate`, it gets read, and the delegate callback (`self.delegate?.dataDidUpdate()`) in the `DataManager` occurs before you set your `FirstScreenViewController` view controller as the `DataManager`'s delegate (on the line `DataManager.shared.delegate = self`). At this point the `DataManager`'s delegate is `nil`, so you do not receive the callback in your view controller.

The correct way to ensure that you always get the delegate callback would be that you set the `DataManager`'s `delegate` before you execute the `fetchDataFromFirestore(date: String)` call.

If this helps you, please consider marking this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I know the problem
The data is saved in the firestore with the date in this format
Jan 10, 2023
Jan 24, 2023
and so on
when get the date i was test getting it with the simulator and the format was the same MMM DD, YYYY, but when turn on the physical device the format was DD MMM, YYYY so I add a code to force the format to be MMM DD, YYYY

```
let topicDay = String(self.currentDateTime.formatted(date: .abbreviated, time: .omitted) )// exp Jan 3, 2023
let dateString = topicDay
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"

let date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateString)

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MMM dd, yyyy"
let newDateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date!)
```